# Determining needed repository for software

Tags: terminal, centos, yum, repository, terminator

I am a beginning linux user (centOS currently). I tried to install the terminator terminal application. I understood that it is not in the default repositories of cent-os but it should be in the epel-release repository.

So I did:

```
yum install epel-release
```

This installed fine, and then:

```
yum install terminator
```

But I get the error:

```
No package terminator available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Why doesn't this work and how do you find out what repository you need for a specific piece of software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps to install Terminator on a fresh install of CentOS 7.

First install the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository:

```
yum install epel-release
```

Then update the newly installed repo:

```
yum update
```

The Terminator package is contained in the nux-desktop repository. You need to **download** the rpm file first before you can then add it to your yum.repos.d directory:

```
wget http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release- 0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

Next, run this command to install the repository:

```
rpm -Uvh nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

Then update the newly installed repo:

```
yum update
```

You are now ready to install terminator:

```
yum install terminator
```

Terminator is now installed and ready to use :)

Comment: Thank you for this. In previous versions I got this from [RPMForge](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/terminator/) and wasn't able to find a work around until this.

Answer (score 1):

Terminator is not a part of [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). It looks like it's a part of [nux-dextop](http://li.nux.ro/repos.html).

Read more about the [different repositories available on CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).

This should work, assuming you are using CentOS 7:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-2.noarch.rpm

yum install http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm

yum install terminator
```

It's worth noting that your `yum install epel-release` likely installed the correct version of epel-release, so the first line is probably not required.

Good luck!